# Verify RSA signature with public key in PEM format in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cryptography

If I have a payload, signature, and a public key (all in bytestring or similar format), how can I verify the signature?

All of the `PublicKey` types I see on Hackage seem to represent keys purely via numbers, for instance:

```hs
PublicKey    

public_size :: Int  -- size of key in bytes

public_n :: Integer -- public p*q

public_e :: Integer -- public exponant e
```

How can I get a `PublicKey` from a PEM file, or simply perform verification directly from the PEM file?

[EDIT from the feedback that no solution attempt was made] - I looked around for solutions, but haven't been able to find anything at all on hoogle that satisfies any type signature I'd expect, like `ByteString -> PublicKey`. I don't want to reimplement this from scratch, as what I'm doing now is just calling out to a python script that performs all of the verification. It would be nice if I didn't need to call out to python though, but can't seem to find any existing code.

Comment: I see this got downvoted - apologies, happy to improve the question from any feedback!

Comment: Have you looked at [OpenSSL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HsOpenSSL-0.11.4.16/docs/OpenSSL-PEM.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a library exposes an interface like `public_n :: Integer`, it means that it's a library that illustrates the RSA operation, not a library for cryptography. A cryptography library would have interfaces like `sign :: Key -> ByteString -> ByteString`. Any cryptography library should be able to parse keys in PEM format.

[OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) is a popular library for cryptography. It isn't always ideal or easy to use, but it's widespread, and you won't be using its quirky C interface since you're using Haskell. So you can use [`HsOpenSSL`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HsOpenSSL), which is a Haskell binding over OpenSSL. (Note: I have never used HsOpenSSL, but it looks sensible.) Use [`OpenSSL.PEM.readPrivateKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HsOpenSSL-0.11.4.16/docs/OpenSSL-PEM.html#v:readPrivateKey) to read a key in PEM format, [`OpenSSL.EVP.Digest.digestLBS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HsOpenSSL-0.11.4.16/docs/OpenSSL-EVP-Digest.html#v:digestLBS) to calculate a digest of the message you want to sign, and [`OpenSSL.EVP.Sign.signBS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HsOpenSSL-0.11.4.16/docs/OpenSSL-EVP-Sign.html#v:signBS) to sign the digest.